# How to Return With a error if input not equals ; batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i 've been working on a batch file to execute programs

```
@echo off
:top
set /p choice=" My Choice = "
if %choice%=="install program.alpha" goto alpha
if %choice%=="install program.beta"  goto beta
:alpha
start="Destination...."
goto top
:beta
start="Destination...."
goto top
```

so my problem is . i can't create a condition that when user input a wrong command so it must return with a error . like user entered that command:

```
install program.gamma
```

or

```
install program.alhfdzbd or something else that not matches the custom commands
```

what can i do???

Comment: You should also be aware that `choice` does *not* change its value when the user just presses _ENTER_, so perhaps you want to clear the variable like `set choice=` (put it between `:top` and `set /p`)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user enters neither `install program.alpha` nor `install program.beta`, just treat the input as invalid.

```
@echo off
:top
set /p choice=" My Choice = "
if "%choice%"=="install program.alpha" goto alpha
if "%choice%"=="install program.beta"  goto beta

:: If you get here, the user has typed something wrong.
echo Invalid selection. Exiting.
exit /b

:alpha
set start="Destination...."
goto top
:beta
set start="Destination...."
goto top
```

Comment: Thanks Man That Was Very Helpful You Made my Day. Thanks a lot. and sorry for this. I am just a beginner and you might think of this at level of shit

Comment: Nah, being bad at something is just the first step to getting good at something.

Comment: You Know i have been working on this setup for weeks and it's perfect now. Means it's like Cortana, Now all have to do is "Install package" even a other user (Who Don't Know Custom Commands) can install anything because i worked Hard on every single command

Comment: I tried writing one of those once for fun. Scope creep made me abandon the project. I hope it works out for you.